# How to get NotFoundException instead of MethodNotAllowedException in Symfony2.3?

Tags: routes, symfony-2.3

I have a controller's method annotated like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/document/remove/", name="document_remove", requirements={"id"="^\d+$"}, defaults={"_format"="json"})
 * @Method({"DELETE"})
 */
public function removeDocumentAction(Request $request)
```

If I try to open "/document/remove/" url in my browser (GET request), I see `MethodNotAllowedException`. That is right, but I want to get a `NotFoundException` instead. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to write an event listener. You are going to subscribe to the kernel exception. Check if the exception is a MethodNotAllowedException and then translate it to a NotFoundException.

```
//Your Event Listener
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;

class ExceptionListener
{
    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        $exception = $event->getException();

        if (!($exception instanceof MethodNotAllowedException)) {
            return;
        }

        $response = new Response($exception->getMessage(),404);

        $event->setResponse($response);
    }
}
```

Have a look at the [Symfony Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html) on how to create and register your event listener.